# Python send jobs to queue processed by Popen

Tags: python, queue, popen

I currently have a working python application, gui with wxpython. I send this application a folder which then gets processed by a command line application via Popen. Each time I run this application it take about 40 mins+ to process before it finishes. While a single job processes I would like to queue up another job, I don't want to submit multiple jobs at the same time, I want to submit one job, while it's processing I want to submit another job, so when the first one finishes it would then just process the next, and so on, but I am unsure of how to go about this and would appreciate some suggestions.

Comment: How do you send folders to the application - presumably since you stated that you have a GUI the user selects a folder?  But more detail  would be critical to get any kind of reasonable answer.

Comment: sorry, yes, using the ui interface, the user selects a folder and hits a go button, so wanted like a server / queue situation.

Comment: Something along the lines of `multiprocessing.Queue` sounds right.  It would require and adjustment to what you call via Popen (or a wrapper function).

Comment: Sounds good, could you point me in the direction of an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you have either a notification that the task has finished being passed back to the GUI or the GUI is checking the state of the task periodically.  In either case you can allow the user to just add to a list of directories to be processed and when your `popen` task has finished take the first one off of the list and start a new `popen` task, (remembering to remove the started one off of the list.

Comment: As I said in my question, I don't want to submit a list of jobs at the start, I want to submit jobs at different times which would then be processed one after the other.

Comment: As I said in my answer - build a list in your GUI, (adding to it at **any** time), and when the current job finishes start a new one if there are currently more in the list.

Answer (score -1):

Use `subprocess.call()`  instead of `Popen`, or use `Popen.wait()`.

Comment: No, this would block his GUI app while the background process ran.  He wants to be able to add things for it to work on later, not wait until it finishes explicitly.